# Does Tableau supports GraphQL based APIs?

Tags: graphql, tableau-api

Most of the client require GraphQL client library to work with GraphQL API. I know that Tableau supports Rest APIs and wanted to understand if it is possible to use GraphQL based APIs with Tableau?

Comment: Tableau [Metadata API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/metadata_api/en-us/index.html#metadata-api-and-graphql) uses GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

Integration of Tableau with GraphQL is supported via a 3rd party plugin provided by [cdata](https://www.cdata.com).

[Documentation](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/graphql-tableau-desktop.rst)